# Is It Possible To Merge Outlook Rules?

Tags: outlook

I have about 10 different Outlook Rules that I created on the fly to move generic emails from various mailing lists to the same sub-folder.

Now I want to merge them all into one rule with OR statements.

Obviously I can open the Rules wizard and manually edit a single Rule copying the addresses from the other rules into it to merge them together.

However, I would like to see if it can be done programmatically (even if it takes much longer than doing it manually!).

Is there a way to manipulate Outlook rules like this?
VBA perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software to do that. An add-in for outlook will do the trick. Power Rules Manager did merge 80 rules and left me with 12.